# spring initializer in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

> I have generated a spring boot application with spring-initializer. when im building the project it gives an unknown error in pom.xml file.
>   Why is this happening and how to reslove it?[error with the pom.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUy2f.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.research</groupId>
<artifactId>patients-api</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>patients-api</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: You need to define your datasource. For JPA to work it has to know a datasource to connect. Like a database.

Comment: Please avoid error screenshots. Copy the stack trace and post it in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is not an error to worry about. Spring Boot 2.1.5.RELEASE has release just a week back and probably the IDE you are using for example STS may not be the latest one.

You have 2 options:

1. update your IDE & Maven and to the latest version [OR]
2. Simply change version `<version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>` to `<version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>` and do a Maven update on the project.

I had a similar issue and I fixed with the above options.

Hope this helps.